# Reading a list from a file

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, with-statement

I want to read from a `.txt` file, which has data saved as in list format.

```
['http://www.example.com/?date=20080301',
 'http://www.example.com/?date=20080302',
 'http://www.example.com/?date=20080303']
```

I have the following code:

```
with open("test.txt", 'r') as file_name:
    for urls in file_name:
        for url in eval(urls):
            print url
```

It worked well with exactly idential file (only different links) and now out of a sudden, it raises an exception:

```
File "<string>", line 1
    ['http://www.example.com/?date=20080301',
                                            ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Avoid the format in the first place?

Comment: It's solved by now, but what do you mean by avoiding the format? thx

Comment: Don't write a Python list literal to the file. Write separate urls with newlines instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
with open("test.txt", 'r') as file_name:
    lists = ast.literal_eval(file_name.read())
    for url in lists:
        print url
```

It's much more efficient than using `eval` because, and quoting from the docs, it "safely evaluate[s] an expression node or a string containing a Python expression."